# Do nodes represented as NIL contribute to the height of a 2-3-4 tree?

Tags: trees, b-tree

Does the following 2-3-4 tree have a height of 3 or 2?

[image: 2-3-4 tree]

If I count from the external nodes i.e. the ones with the square boxes then **height should be 3**.
Not sure if they are to be included in the height as they are represented as NIL.
If they are not to be included then the **height of the tree should be 2.**

Any clarification on this?

Answer (score 1):

Citing from [the Wikipedia article on B-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2%E2%80%933%E2%80%934_tree)

> Every node (leaf or internal) is a 2-node, 3-node or a 4-node, and holds one, two, or three data elements, respectively.

Thus, since the squares in the bottom row do not hold data elements, they are not nodes of the 2-3-4 tree.

Then, using the definition of height from the answer to the post [what is the difference between tree depth and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603692/what-is-the-difference-between-tree-depth-and-height), the height of your tree is 2.